# Bootstrap Cards - third card no taller than 2 others in same row

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get a row of 3 cards, whereby the row extends to the max-height of card #1 or card #2 based on their content, and the third card to also get the same max height but overflow-y:scroll even when the content is longer than cards 1 & 2.

I can get the first two cards extending to the tallest of either, but can't seem to limit the third card to this height.

EDIT: Solved with JS > https://codepen.io/chrisj75/pen/jOmbEEQ

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Hello, world!</title>  <body>
<div class='container'>
  <input type='button' value='Fix Height' onclick='fixHeight();' />
  <div class='row'>
  <div class='card-group col-md-12'>
    <div class='card col-md-4'>
    <div id='card1'>
      Card #1
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce id mollis tellus. Proin faucibus mauris non felis placerat, non posuere nibh tristique. Quisque elementum quam urna, tempus iaculis augue convallis ullamcorper. Proin ac laoreet augue. Morbi quis ipsum turpis. Nullam finibus blandit sem, fringilla semper diam tincidunt quis. Nam venenatis dictum eleifend. Donec rutrum non lectus et lobortis. Donec congue, nunc eget consectetur tempus, massa arcu ornare eros, ac scelerisque mauris velit ut libero.


    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='card'>
      <div id='card2'>
      Card #2
      Aliquam in nibh cursus, molestie erat in, congue eros. In volutpat vel orci in tempor. Duis quis sodales leo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tempus sapien pharetra, imperdiet tellus et, facilisis nisl. Cras erat quam, hendrerit in aliquet at, bibendum at turpis. Cras sodales pellentesque mauris sit amet venenxatis. Proin ac nisl viverra, ornare sapien eget, condimentum velit. Nam iaculis ex sed sapien ultricies, vitae sollicitudin leo sagittis. Praesent ante tortor, auctor quis mauris sed, rhoncus elementum dolor. Curabitur sollicitudin non mi vitae ultricies. Vestibulum justo lacus, hendrerit eget mattis quis, maximus id purus.
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='card col-md-4'>
      <div id='card3'>
      Card #3
      Aliquam in nibh cursus, molestie erat in, congue eros. In volutpat vel orci in tempor. Duis quis sodales leo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tempus sapien pharetra, imperdiet tellus et, facilisis nisl. Cras erat quam, hendrerit in aliquet at, bibendum at turpis. Cras sodales pellentesque mauris sit amet venenatis. Proin ac nisl viverra, ornare sapien eget, condimentum velit. Nam iaculis ex sed sapien ultricies, vitae sollicitudin leo sagittis. Praesent ante tortor, auctor quis mauris sed, rhoncus elementum dolor. Curabitur sollicitudin non mi vitae ultricies. Vestibulum justo lacus, hendrerit eget mattis quis, maximus id purus.
                Aliquam in nibh cursus, molestie erat in, congue eros. In volutpat vel orci in tempor. Duis quis sodales leo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tempus sapien pharetra, imperdiet tellus et, facilisis nisl. Cras erat quam, hendrerit in aliquet at, bibendum at turpis. Cras sodales pellentesque mauris sit amet venenatis. Proin ac nisl viverra, ornare sapien eget, condimentum velit. Nam iaculis ex sed sapien ultricies, vitae sollicitudin leo sagittis. Praesent ante tortor, auctor quis mauris sed, rhoncus elementum dolor. Curabitur sollicitudin non mi vitae ultricies. Vestibulum justo lacus, hendrerit eget mattis quis, maximus id purus.
                Aliquam in nibh cursus, molestie erat in, congue eros. In volutpat vel orci in tempor. Duis quis sodales leo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tempus sapien pharetra, imperdiet tellus et, facilisis nisl. Cras erat quam, hendrerit in aliquet at, bibendum at turpis. Cras sodales pellentesque mauris sit amet venenatis. Proin ac nisl viverra, ornare sapien eget, condimentum velit. Nam iaculis ex sed sapien ultricies, vitae sollicitudin leo sagittis. Praesent ante tortor, auctor quis mauris sed, rhoncus elementum dolor. Curabitur sollicitudin non mi vitae ultricies. Vestibulum justo lacus, hendrerit eget mattis quis, maximus id purus.
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#card1, #card2, #card3 {padding:2rem;}
#card3 {overflow-y:scroll;}
.hidden {display:none !important;}
```

JS

```
function fixHeight() {
  $('#card3').addClass('hidden');

  var card1 = $('#card1').height() ;
  var card2 = $('#card2').height() ;

  h = Math.max(card1,card2) ;
  //window.alert(h);
  $('#card3').height(h).removeClass('hidden')
}
```

Comment: Can we see your example? Hard to help without seeing exactly what you're dealing with!

Comment: Got it working with JS... wondering if there's a pure CSS alternative? [link added]